# Parse log for Phone number and BYE via powershell

Tags: parsing, powershell, logging

I need to parse phone numbers from a log file (which is a .txt).

I need to find the phone number along with the timestamp and date and then the corresponding terminated request (which is when the caller hangs up) for that phone number. All calls into the system are iniated with DNAME and ended with TERMINATED.

I've used the `select-string` command but i cant filter the data effectively

the data is as follows :

`13/08/2015 08:57:46:849 | L:4831.1[Line:10003<<XXXXXXXXXX]:  Updated OutCID:'Conference_Call' and DNName: 'CALLER    '`

`13/08/2015 09:00:42:118 | Leg L:4839.1[Line:10003<<XXXXXXXXXX] is terminated: Cause: BYE from 66.23.190.100:5060`

all phone numbers have been replaced by XXXXXXXX for safety.

Does anyone know of a more powerful command to do this?

more data

`13/08/2015 08:55:27:554 | Session 1230943 of leg L:4820.1[Line:10003<<180012334545] is confirmed
13/08/2015 08:55:49:766 | Answer to offerer immediateily, other party (L:4820.1[Line:10003<<180012334545]) doesn't support re-invite
13/08/2015 08:55:49:972 | L:4820.1[Line:10003<<18001234545]:  Updated OutCID: 'Conference_Call' and DNName: 'Joe Brown    '
13/08/2015 08:55:49:972 | L:4820.1[Line:10003<<180012334545]: Target refresh is not possible: Line:10003<<18001334545 doesn't support re-INVITE
13/08/2015 08:55:49:972 | [CM503010]: Call(C:4820): Making route(s) from Line:10003<<18001334545 to <sip:811@127.0.0.1:5060>
13/08/2015 08:55:49:972 | [Flow] Call(C:4820): has built target endpoint: Ivr:811 for call from L:4820.1[Line:10003<<191944345740]
13/08/2015 08:55:49:972 | [CM503004]: Call(C:4820): Route 1: from L:4820.1[Line:10003<<18001233545] to T:Ivr:811@[Dev:sip:811@127.0.0.1:40600;rinstance=19fdaa2fa620113c]
13/08/2015 08:55:49:972 | [CM503027]: Call(C:4820): From: Line:10003<<18001334545 ("Glen Peaks    " <sip:180012334545@98.100.70.194:5060>)  to  T:Ivr:811@[Dev:sip:811@127.0.0.1:40600;rinstance=19fdaa2fa620113c]
13/08/2015 08:55:49:972 | [Flow] Call(C:4820): making call from L:4820.1[Line:10003<<18001233545] to T:Ivr:811@[Dev:sip:811@127.0.0.1:40600;rinstance=19fdaa2fa620113c]
13/08/2015 08:55:50:027 | [CM503025]: Call(C:4820): Calling T:Ivr:811@[Dev:sip:811@127.0.0.1:40600;rinstance=19fdaa2fa620113c] for L:4820.1[Line:10003<<180012334545]
13/08/2015 08:55:50:181 | L:4820.3[Ivr:811] has joined to L:4820.1[Line:10003<<18001234545]
13/08/2015 08:55:50:181 | L:4820.1[Line:10003<<19914345740]: Terminating targets, reason: SIP ;cause=200 ;text="Call completed elsewhere"`

Comment: What has you done so far?, do you have any code already?, also is the 'xxxx' number is only digits or has a dashes or other signs?

Comment: No, they're just 11 digits. However i've been able to exclude lines via `select string  -path "path" -pattern Dname and -exclude added` this gives me alot of data which is less verbose but not usable

Comment: Are the initiation and termination events always sequential in the log, or can there be other session events in between a given sessions initiation and termination events?

Comment: No, sometimes the calls go different places within the log and the variance from initiation and termination can vary depending on alot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, though regarding the TimeStamp and Phone number you can use this:

```
$Array = @()
$text = cat C:\Test.txt
$TimeStamp = "\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{4}\s\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{3}"
$Number = "\d{10}"
foreach ($Line in $text)
{
$Result = "" | Select TimeStamp,Number
$Result.TimeStamp = $Line | select-string -Pattern $TimeStamp -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } 
$result.Number = $Line | select-string -Pattern $Number -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } 
$Array += $Result
}
```

Please provide more info for the CALLER,Terminated etc. so i can help you find the correct Regex

Comment: CALLER is the name of the caller on the caller ID if there is one. Terminated is the line generated when a caller hangs up. and DNAME is the name and phone number when a caller connects to the desired destination. This is a SIP log.

Comment: can you show real example for those to see how it looks